# higher level Python GUI toolkit, e.g. pass dict for TreeView/Grid

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

Started my first Python pet project using PyGTK. Though it is a really powerful GUI toolkit and looks excellent, I have some pet peeves. So I thought about transitioning to something else, as it's not yet too extensive. Had a look around on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+gui+toolkit) and [python documentation](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming), but didn't get a good overview.

What's nice about PyGTK:

- Glade files
- self.signal_autoconnect({...})
- self.get_widget() as __getattr__

This is bugging me however:

- manual gobject.idle_add(lambda: ... and False)
- no standard functionality to save application/window states
- TreeView needs array building
- widget.get_selection().get_selected(), model.get_value(iter, liststore_index)

**TreeView**: Because this is the main interface element, it's the most distracting. Basically my application builds a list of dictionaries to be displayed name=column+row=>value. To display it using GTK there needs to be a manual conversion process, ordering, typecasts. This seems a lot of overhead, and I wished for something more object-oriented here. PyGtk has many abstractions atop gtk+ but still seems rather low-levelish. I'd prefer to pass my dict as-is and have columns pre-defined somehow. (GtkBuilder can predefine TreeView columns, but this doesn't solve the data representation overhead.)

When I get a mousclick on my TreeView list, I also have to convert everything back into my application data structures. And it's also irksome that PyGTK doesn't wrap gtk+ calls with gobject.idle itself, if run from a non-main thread. Right now there is a lot of GUI code that I believe shouldn't be necessary, or could be rationalized away.

**?** So, are there maybe additional wrappers on top of PyGTK. Or which other toolkit supports simpler interfaces for displaying a Grid / TreeView. I've read a lot about wxPython being everyones favourite, but it's less mature on Linux. And **PyQT** seems to be mostly the same abstraction level as PyGTK. Haven't used **TkInter** much so don't know about if it has simpler interfaces, but it anyway looks unattractive. As does **PyFLTK**. PyJamas sounds fascinating, but is already too far out (Desktop application).

.

So, GUI toolkit with dict -> Grid display. Which would you pick?

.

Just as exhibit, this is my current TreeView mapping function. Sort of works, but I would rather have something standard:

```
    #-- fill a treeview
    #
    # Adds treeviewcolumns/cellrenderers and liststore from a data dictionary.
    # Its datamap and the table contents can be supplied in one or two steps.
    # When new data gets applied, the columns aren't recreated.
    #
    # The columns are created according to the datamap, which describes cell
    # mapping and layout. Columns can have multiple cellrenderers, but usually
    # there is a direct mapping to a data source key from entries.
    #
    # datamap = [  #  title   width    dict-key    type,  renderer,  attrs  
    #               ["Name",   150,  ["titlerow",   str,    "text",    {} ]  ],
    #               [False,     0,   ["interndat",  int,     None,     {} ]  ],
    #               ["Desc",   200,  ["descriptn",  str,    "text",    {} ],  ["icon",str,"pixbuf",{}]  ],
    #
    # An according entries list then would contain a dictionary for each row:
    #   entries = [ {"titlerow":"first", "interndat":123}, {"titlerow":"..."}, ]
    # Keys not mentioned in the datamap get ignored, and defaults are applied
    # for missing cols. All values must already be in the correct type however.
    #
    @staticmethod
    def columns(widget, datamap=[], entries=[], pix_entry=False):

        # create treeviewcolumns?
        if (not widget.get_column(0)):
            # loop through titles
            datapos = 0
            for n_col,desc in enumerate(datamap):

                # check for title
                if (type(desc[0]) != str):
                    datapos += 1  # if there is none, this is just an undisplayed data column
                    continue
                # new tvcolumn
                col = gtk.TreeViewColumn(desc[0])  # title
                col.set_resizable(True)
                # width
                if (desc[1] > 0):
                    col.set_sizing(gtk.TREE_VIEW_COLUMN_FIXED)
                    col.set_fixed_width(desc[1])

                # loop through cells
                for var in xrange(2, len(desc)):
                    cell = desc[var]
                    # cell renderer
                    if (cell[2] == "pixbuf"):
                        rend = gtk.CellRendererPixbuf()  # img cell
                        if (cell[1] == str):
                            cell[3]["stock_id"] = datapos  # for stock icons
                            expand = False
                        else:
                            pix_entry = datapos
                            cell[3]["pixbuf"] = datapos
                    else:
                        rend = gtk.CellRendererText()    # text cell
                        cell[3]["text"] = datapos
                        col.set_sort_column_id(datapos)  # only on textual cells

                    # attach cell to column
                    col.pack_end(rend, expand=cell[3].get("expand",True))
                    # apply attributes
                    for attr,val in cell[3].iteritems():
                        col.add_attribute(rend, attr, val)
                    # next
                    datapos += 1

                # add column to treeview
                widget.append_column(col)
            # finalize widget
            widget.set_search_column(2)   #??
            widget.set_reorderable(True)

        # add data?
        if (entries):
            #- expand datamap            
            vartypes = []  #(str, str, bool, str, int, int, gtk.gdk.Pixbuf, str, int)
            rowmap = []    #["title", "desc", "bookmarked", "name", "count", "max", "img", ...]
            if (not rowmap):
                for desc in datamap:
                    for var in xrange(2, len(desc)):
                        vartypes.append(desc[var][3])  # content types
                        rowmap.append(desc[var][0])    # dict{} column keys in entries[] list
            # create gtk array storage
            ls = gtk.ListStore(*vartypes)   # could be a TreeStore, too

            # prepare for missing values, and special variable types
            defaults = {
                str: "",
                unicode: u"",
                bool: False,
                int: 0,
                gtk.gdk.Pixbuf: gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_data("\0\0\0\0",gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,True,8,1,1,4)
            }
            if gtk.gdk.Pixbuf in vartypes:
                pix_entry = vartypes.index(gtk.gdk.Pixbuf) 

            # sort data into gtk liststore array
            for row in entries:
                # generate ordered list from dictionary, using rowmap association
                row = [   row.get( skey , defaults[vartypes[i]] )   for i,skey   in enumerate(rowmap)   ]

                # autotransform string -> gtk image object
                if (pix_entry and type(row[pix_entry]) == str):
                    row[pix_entry] = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(row[pix_entry])

                # add
                ls.append(row)   # had to be adapted for real TreeStore (would require additional input for grouping/level/parents)

            # apply array to widget
            widget.set_model(ls)
            return ls

        pass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Kiwi](http://www.async.com.br/projects/kiwi/), maybe? Especially with its [ObjectList](http://unpythonic.blogspot.com/2006/11/pygtk-lists-made-easy-with-kiwi.html).

Update: I think Kiwi development has moved to [PyGTKHelpers](http://packages.python.org/pygtkhelpers/).

Comment: Have to buy some upvotes. And something to beat myself up. Actually I had read about Kiwi before, but somehow overlooked it at implementation time. That's really what I wanted. Just have to check out if you can get the ObjectLists content back as-is in a signal callback.

Answer (score 4):

I hadn't come across Kiwi before.  Thanks, Johannes Sasongko.

Here are some more tooklits that I keep bookmarked.  Some of these are wrappers around other toolkits (GTK, wxWidgets) while others stand alone:

- [AVC](http://avc.inrim.it/html/)
- [Dabo](http://dabodev.com/)
- [pyFLTK](http://pyfltk.sourceforge.net/)
- [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/)
- [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/)
- [PyGUI](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python_gui/)
- [uxPython](http://www.uxpython.com/)
- [Wax](http://zephyrfalcon.org/labs/wax.html)
- [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/)
- [wxpita](http://code.google.com/p/wxpita/)
- [WxWrappers](http://wiki.wxpython.org/WxWrappers)

(I've included a few that were already mentioned for the sake of others who come across this post.  I would have posted this as a comment, but it's a bit too long.)

Comment: Excellent points in your list. I've seen Dabo before, which seemed seriously higher level and especially provides a data view above a treeview/grid. However, couldn't find a real API documentation and so I'm unsure if the UI components can be used independently from database sources.

Comment: And AVC sounds even better! "AVC is a multiplatform, fully automatic, live connection among graphical interface widgets and application variables for the python language."

Answer (score 3):

See also [pygtkhelpers' ObjectList](https://pygabriel.wordpress.com/2010/05/24/writing-pygtk-applications-with-style-using-pygtkhelpers/)

Answer (score 1):

[I would suggest taking a look at wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115495/is-python-any-good-for-gui-development/115654#115654). I found it really easy to pick up and very powerful too although I'd have to admit I've not done a lot with Treeviews myself.

wxWidgets calls the equivalent control a [wxTreeCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.6/wx_wxtreectrl.html)

**[Edit]** The [wxDataViewTreeCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_data_view_tree_ctrl.html) might actually be of more use in your case.

Comment: How does that answer his question?  While it's been a little while since I've used these two libraries, my feeling was that if anything, PyGTK is higher-level than wxPython.  I don't see anything in the wxTreeCtrl docs to suggest you can, e.g., just pass a dictionary and be done with it.

Comment: It's not as helpful as I first though. I'm sure I'd seen an example on the wxPython website doing something like this but now I can't find it :-/

Comment: I'll investigate this anyhow. WX uses GTK as backend, so at least can't be a visual downgrade. But since it's a compat wrapper, it's probably common denominator abstraction level. But then, I'm mostly interested in the TreeView API. Just haven't seen the relevant doc yet...