# Is wxPython Needed on the End  User's Computer

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, tkinter

I am making programs that solve and show work for math problems. I would like to add a GUI, and I think wxPython will be best. If I use wxPython for the GUI, will the end user need wxPython on their computer in order to use the program with the GUI? If not, what would should I use?

These apps will be used on mostly Windows, but I would also like them to work on Macs and Linux. I'm not for sure if any Python GUI elements will work on Android through SL4A, but if you know any, that would be appreciated.

Also, I know Tkinter is bundled with Python, but is it a dying technique, as I have read?

Thanks!

Comment: tkinter is only dying because people keep parroting that. Tk (upon which tkinter is based) continues to evolve and improve. It is a perfectly fine toolkit for a very large variety of problems. It's popularity may be dying, but its usefulness is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tools for packaging a python program and its libraries into an executable that can run on its own.  I keep this list handy:

http://www.freehackers.org/Packaging_a_python_program

I'm sure at least one of those tools will handle wxPython, because I did it a few years ago.  (Sorry, but I don't remember which one.)

Yes, tkinter's popularity has been waning for years.  See this question for some more options:

[higher level Python GUI toolkit, e.g. pass dict for TreeView/Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136128/higher-level-python-gui-toolkit-e-g-pass-dict-for-treeview-grid)

Comment: According to the overview pyinstaller handles wxwidgets (http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/SupportedPackages)

Comment: Come to think of it, that's probably the one I was using.  It handles all three major platforms as well.

Comment: I'm sold on PyInstaller, but if I use PyInstaller with wxPython, will the person I distribute the app to need wxPython installed to use the program?

Comment: As I remember it, no. wxPython will be packaged along with your code. You *may* have to read some documentation and gather the wxWidgets libraries for each platform when you assemble the package.

Answer (score 1):

If your software is mostly about the complicated processing, with a fairly simple UI, tkinter is probably fine

Answer (score 0):

I am using [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) for this without any problems. Worked for me on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter comes with Python, so it can be handier in some respects just because of that. On the other hand, wxPython uses the native widgets of the OS (which has it's own set of pros and cons). I personally prefer wxPython. But no, Tkinter is not dead to my knowledge.

You can use py2exe to bundle up your app on Windows or you could use cx_freeze or bb_freeze. There's also PyInstaller, which I think can create some kind of Linux bundle, but the docs are kind of confusing. For Mac, see py2app.

I'm not aware of any specific Python GUI toolkits for Android.

Comment: tkinter uses many native widgets on windows and OSX, and has done so for a very long time.

Comment: From what I'd read over the years, Tkinter was supposedly drawing the controls, not actually using the native widgets. However, I know you've got a ton of Tkinter experience, so you would definitely know better than I. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

PyInstaller.

install and run.

cmd -> python pyinstaller.py NAMEOFSCRIPT.py --onefile --noconsole.

easy as 123.